# Error in writing to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing some data to a database using php. 99% of the time, the data is correctly written to the database. But sometimes, blank data is being inserted into the database. I dont think its a issue with my code, since I can write the data to the database most of the time.

If the server on which the database resides have a slow internet connection, or if the user have a slow internet connection in their pc, can this happen?

Actually there is a slight mistake..Seems like the data that gets blank, comes from a session variable. How can be the session variable get blanked at some time ?

This is the code by which the data get stored into the session variable:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $email))
$count = 2;
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6}+$/',$key))
$count = 2;
if(!$count)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE verify = '$key' AND email = '$email'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1)
 {
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $_SESSION['id'] = $row[0];
  $_SESSION['name'] = $row[1];
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  $_SESSION['pass'] = $row[3];
  $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
  mysql_close();
 }
}
```

When it happens, all the 5 variables id, name, email, pass and key, becomes blank. Email, and Key is not taken from the Database. The key field contains only alphanumeric content. So is there a way the data taken from the database as well at the GET variables to go blank? ( but even then $count should 1). Because, only if $count is 1, can the data be written to the new table ( where it get blanked )

There are 2 forms. When the user completes the first form, that data is stored in a table test, and a verification mail is sent to them. From the verification link, i find out their key and email, and check the table test, to see whether they are valid. If they are valid ( that means $count is 1 ), then a new form is displayed to the user, where they are asked to enter few more details. Then all the data ( this new data, and also the data that was written to the table test ), shall be written to a new table.

This is where things go wrong. The new data is written perfectly to the new table. But the old data, that was stored in the table test, and copied to the session variable, becomes blank sometimes. I have posted its code above, showing how the session variables are set.

It shall be helpful if someone could point out my mistake, if its something wrong in my code.

Comment: To answer your question, if the data is never sent, then the database won't write.  But if it's writing blank data, then something else is happening.  What type of data are you trying to write?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I believe the data is being sent 99% of the time. The data is basically alpha numeric content

Comment: We cannot answer this without seeing your code. There may be cases where empty form posts are processed, or a search engine robot can access your script.

Comment: Actually there is a slight mistake..Seems like the data that gets blank, comes from a session variable

Comment: When you hear hoofprints, do not look for zebras.  99.999 % of the time the problem is with your code, not with the database, network, or operating system you are depending on.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Nope. Empty form posts cant get in. I have kept both server side and client validation with regex to see that, that form element contains only allowed characters. If not, error shall be displayed

Comment: i have posted the code by which data is written to the session variable

Comment: [mysql_query() is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should rewrite that.

Comment: I'm familiar with only mysql_query and not the PDO or mysqli query. Can the problem be caused because of mysql_query ?

Answer (score 1):

Programmers have at least five tactics to make sure data gets written to a database.

1. Check the content of variables for sanity before writing.
2. Design the database to reject bad data.
3. Trap errors. All of them.
4. Read back what you just wrote.
5. A verbose mode that writes to a log file.

Comment: 1. The content to be written is checked beforehand. But the data that comes as blank is stored in a session variable. The data is stored into the session variable from another tables in the database.                                                              Rest of it, i dont think i know how to do

Comment: Is it checked for length? Is it checked for length after you trim leading and trailing spaces? Is it checked before it's stored in the session variable? Is it checked when it's read back from the session variable?

Comment: Well, i dont trim any characters from it. I just check whether it contains only the characters that I allows in that field. Only then, the data is posted. No, its not checked before its written to the session variable, since the data is taken from the database. Its not checked. But if the session variable is blank, then the data written to the db shall be blank

Comment: i have posted the code by which the data is written to the session variable

Comment: You *must* check the return values of mysql_query() and mysql_numrows(). As it stands, you have no idea whether they're failing. But you should rewrite that part of the code anyway. Pay attention to return values. What do you think might happen if $count isn't equal to 1?

Comment: If $ count is not 1, the session variables are not set. But then, unless it is 1, the data cannot be written to the new table ( where the blank data occurs).

Comment: Actually i do check the return value of mysql_num_rows. That is what stored in $count. I check whether it is 1

Comment: It doesn't return 1 on failure.

Comment: But if its not 1, then the new data cant be written. But the datais written, but that is blank. So $count have to be 1.How can that be ?

Comment: "But then, unless it is 1, the data cannot be written to the new table ( where the blank data occurs)." Based on the code you posted, I don't trust your judgement on that matter.  You seem to want to trust your own logic and knowledge of your own intent rather than looking at the values and checking error codes. Writing code that way doesn't scale well.

Comment: My logic might be wrong. I have no problem with that. I just want to see where i went wrong. Unless it is 1, the new form where they enter some other details wont come up. But actually those new details are written to the database, meaning it have to be 1. Only the columns where the session variable data is used, it gets blanked.

Comment: i have edited the thread to make it more clear. Kindly read through it